# tgreenplumGPload - Insert is not working

Tags: talend, greenplum

When i try to execute gpload from Talend based on windows server. it is not fetching the data at target table. and also not giving any error in job execution.therefore, Insert is failing without error.

Basically , inserts /merge fails to output into target table. However , it is reading external table. issue is dumping source external data into target table only

**I'm finding the way**

How to use tgreenplumGPload basic setting and advanced setting. so that it start taking insert operation.

I already went and check this component setting from talend help centre. but did not found any scenario.

Tried :

**tgreenplumGPload  Setting screenshot :**

[image: Basic Setting]

[image: Advance Setting]

Advanced thanks.